# Grid.MVC to bind with specific condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, grid.mvc

Scenario: Using `Grid.Mvc`, and binding it with `ViewBag`(this contains model list).
I have model appointment's list in a viewbag. and in UI i have two grids, one for showing visited appointments, other for appointments which are not visited.

`Grid 1: HasVisited == True` 
`Grid 2: HasVisited == False`

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Named("Grid1").Columns(columns =>
                 {
                    columns.Add(c => c.StartTime).Titled("Date").Filterable(true).Sortable(true);
                    columns.Add(c => c.Patient).Titled("Patient").Filterable(true).Sortable(true);
                }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
```

The above is the `Grid.Mvc` grid implementation. Do we have any ways to bind the grid with specified condition.?

Comment: i never used Grid.Mvc but i assume `Model.Where(d=>d.HasVisited==true)` condition on the  place of `Model`  should work for you.

Comment: Thank you this worked fine.

Comment: happy to know , should i add it as answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just Change `Model` to `Model.Where(d=>d.HasVisited==true)` for filtering the data.

Answer (score 0):

After modification;

```
@Html.Grid(Model.Where(d=>d.HasVisited==true)).Named("Grid1").Columns(columns =>
                 {
                    columns.Add(c => c.StartTime).Titled("Date").Filterable(true).Sortable(true);
                    columns.Add(c => c.Patient).Titled("Patient").Filterable(true).Sortable(true);
                }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
```